# Vue Method works on update but not on mounted

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue method that is called at `mounted` lifecycle hook. For some reason, it does not work if I refresh but does if the browser is hot reladed in development. I expect an object to be returned. Instead, it's undefined.

```
data () {
  return {
    randomAd: '',
    startingIndex: 0,
    businesses: [...]
  }
},
mounted () {
    this.getRandomAd()
  },
  methods: {
    getRandomAd () {
      console.log(this.businesses.length)
      let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.businesses.length)
      console.log(randomNum)
      this.startingIndex = randomNum
      let randomAd = this.businesses[randomNum]
      this.randomAd = randomAd
      console.log(this.businesses[randomNum])
    },
```

The output of the three console logs are: `[__ob__: Observer]`, `0,` and `undefined`. The first object contains all the data but it seems to break at the `randomNum`.

When the browser is hot reloaded I get what I expect with `[__ob__: Observer]`, `17`, `11`.

**Update**

I just realized that the data comes from firebase. If I remove the firebase `businesses` array and create a dummy one this code works. Do I need to add an `async/await` somewhere? The thing I find weird is that the first console.log of the array shows the data already there.

Comment: `mounted()` fired only when the component was mount. You need to check if the data from firebase is `null` or not, if not that's the time you need to fired that event `getRandomAd()`. I think much better to use `computed` property.

Comment: Thanks @JohnReyM.Baylen, I had this in a `computed` before and it was working great. Then the client wanted to create a button that ran the random functionality again and I didn't think I could do that with a computed so I moved it to a method that set data properties. Maybe the wrong move?

Comment: `firebase` -> vuex store it on `state` using `mutation` and `action`. When method fired, you can now get the data from state not in `computed()`. This is my suggestion, but in the end, it's up to you.